# inet_pton warning when use webserver behinds a reverse proxy

Tags: server

My server architecture is like below

```
0.0.0.0:80  =>  127.0.0.1:6081  =>  127.0.0.1:82
  HAProxy          Varnish             Nginx
```

I trace real client IP by uncommenting these lines in `local.xml`

```
<remote_addr_headers><!-- list headers that contain real client IP if webserver is behind a reverse proxy -->
    <header1>HTTP_X_REAL_IP</header1>
    <header2>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</header2>
</remote_addr_headers>
```

It can get real client IP properly. In order information, `Placed from IP` shows only real client IP.

But, I watch `system.log`, every visit to the website, this log appends:

```
ERR (3): Warning: inet_pton(): Unrecognized address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1  in /some/where/overtherainbow/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Http.php on line 149
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is real client IP.

Code snipet from Http.php (line 149 is `return` line)

```
 public function getRemoteAddr($ipToLong = false)
    {
        if (is_null($this->_remoteAddr)) {
            $headers = $this->getRemoteAddrHeaders();
            foreach ($headers as $var) {
                if ($this->_getRequest()->getServer($var, false)) {
                    $this->_remoteAddr = $_SERVER[$var];
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!$this->_remoteAddr) {
                $this->_remoteAddr = $this->_getRequest()->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');
            }
        }

        if (!$this->_remoteAddr) {
            return false;
        }

        return $ipToLong ? inet_pton($this->_remoteAddr) : $this->_remoteAddr;
    }
```

`$this->_remoteAddr` contains 3 IP addresses as `string`, it causes the warning log.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can contain many IP addresses when forwarding multiple times. This is untested but try adding this to your index.php:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '') { 
    $arr = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = trim($arr[0]);
}
```

or if Magento is already using HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, perhaps:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '') { 
    $arr = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = trim($arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: I use phpinfo to inspect $_SERVE keys and find out your second code snipet should be used. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is now resolved as of Magento 1.9.3.9

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Http.php

Replace **public function getRemoteAddr**

with

```
    public function getRemoteAddr($ipToLong = false)
{
    if (is_null($this->_remoteAddr)) {
        $headers = $this->getRemoteAddrHeaders();
        foreach ($headers as $var) {
            if ($var != 'REMOTE_ADDR' && $this->_getRequest()->getServer($var, false)) {
                $this->_remoteAddr = $_SERVER[$var];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$this->_remoteAddr) {
            $this->_remoteAddr = $this->_getRequest()->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');
        }
    }

    if (!$this->_remoteAddr) {
        return false;
    }

    if (strpos($this->_remoteAddr, ',') !== false) {
        $ipList = explode(',', $this->_remoteAddr);
        $this->_remoteAddr = trim(reset($ipList));
    }

    return $ipToLong ? inet_pton($this->_remoteAddr) : $this->_remoteAddr;
}
```